# PIL .getdata() returning array size larger than image width times image height

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to get pixel value of an RGB image in the form of a NumPy array, then reshaping it and then storing it as an Image. However, the new Image size is much larger than the original Image. I also check the size of the NumPy array created - it is exactly thrice the product of image width and height.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as NP

img = Image.open('C:/Wallpapers/99820.jpg').convert('RGB')
pxls = NP.array(img.getdata())
res = img.size
new_img = pxls.reshape((img.height, img.width, 3))
new_img2 = Image.fromarray(new_img.astype(NP.uint8))
new_img2.save('C:/Wallpapers/new.png', 'PNG')
```

The original image was 56.3KB was and new was 185KB. Why is that?

I tried the above code. I was expecting the NumPy array size to be equal to image Width x Height as the NumPy array is 2D with its elements being of size 3 for each of r,g and b.

Answer (score 3):

You're reading a JPEG image; JPEGs are lossily compressed. PNGs (which you're outputting) are losslessly compressed.

If you want a smaller output, save a JPEG (with a suitable quality setting).

As for why the array is exactly thrice as large as `width * height`, you have an RGB image - that's 3 channels per pixel.